# Copying a database in MySQL, how to copy views?

Tags: php, mysql, database, view, backup

Trying to copy a database into a new database, using a PHP script that runs SQL queries on a MySQL server. The code I have sofar is:

```
$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $new_news CHARACTER SET UTF8;");
$results = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES FROM $old_news");
$table_list = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

foreach($table_list as $table_row){
    foreach($table_row as $table){
        $results = $dbh->query("SELECT table_type FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema = '$old_news' and table_name = '$table'");
        $table_type = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $table_type = $table_type['table_type'];
        if($table_type == 'BASE TABLE'){
            echo "Creating table $table and populating...\n";
            $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE $new_news.$table LIKE $old_news.$table");
            $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO $new_news.$table SELECT * FROM $old_news.$table");
        }else if($table_type == 'VIEW'){
            //echo "Creating view $table...\n";
            //$dbh->exec("CREATE VIEW $new_news.$table LIKE $old_news.$table");
            echo "$table is a view, which cannot be copied atm\n";  
        }else{
            echo "Skipping $table_type $table, unsupported type\n"; 
        }
    }
}
```

This currently looks at all tables in $old_news, finds the table type in the information_schema, and creates an identical table in $new_news depending on the type. For tables, it creates the table structure the same, then 'INSERT INTO SELECT' to fill them.

How do you copy a view without mysqldump the entire database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views-table.html) to see the view definition, or SHOW CREATE VIEW for the whole statement.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to go with `SHOW CREATE VIEW` for every view which returns the view creation syntax.

See **[12.4.5.10. SHOW CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html)** for details.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me. It will copy all views from source_database to target_database

```
$link = mysql_connect('hostname', 'user', 'password',false,128) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('source_database') or die(mysql_error());

$qry=mysql_query("SHOW FULL TABLES IN source_database WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW'");

while ($rows= mysql_fetch_object($qry)){
        $view_name=$rows->Tables_in_techdb_beta;
        $select_view=mysql_query("SHOW CREATE VIEW ".$view_name);
        while ($view_rows= mysql_fetch_object($select_view)){
            foreach($view_rows as $key=>$val){
                if ($key=='Create View'){
                    $views_array[]=$val;
                }
            }
        }
}
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($views_array);
$link2 = mysql_connect('hostname', 'user', 'password',false,128) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('target_database') or die(mysql_error());
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
foreach($views_array as $key => $val){
    $sql=trim($val);
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```